# Watch Icons and Items in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When I hover over a JObject variable in my C# code, I see a watch window pop up. When I expand that, I see the following image:

[image]

**Questions**

1. What does the blue symbol/icon next to ChildrenTokens signify?
2. Where is a comprehensive list of such symbols/icons?
3. We all see **ChildrenTokens** listed in the watch window. However, when I am in code and try to access the ChildrenTokens property, intellisense doesn't show it. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: It's `protected`, which is why you don't see it in intellisense. But it's a property (the wrench) which is why it's showing with all the other properties. The blue ribbon (?) is indicating `protected`. I'm not sure where there is a comprehensive list.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.140) has the main icons but doesn't show the overlay for protected (it does at the bottom but it's different)

Comment: I could see why intellisense might list a protected property, but I don't understand why it would list that property and allow access to its value while the running code cannot access its value. Shouldn't the running code have access to any property listed in a watch?

Comment: Note that you can also click the expand arrow next to `Non-Public` members. You can see private fields in there too...

Comment: Yes, that clarifies all. Thanks.

Comment: Also note you are seeing the Dynamic View as well since `JObject` is a `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` (by way of `JToken`) so you can see its `dynamic` aspects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see from [JObject Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ChildrenTokens.htm), `ChildrenTokens` is a `protected override` `property`. The icons with the wrench displays Properties; The blue icon (possibly a lock) is indicating that the property is protected. This would explain why you cannot access it via Intellisense.

You can find a list of the icons and overlays here for VS2015 here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.140)

Note that the icons vary depending on where you are viewing them.

Comment: Shame on Microsoft not only for varying the icons but also for not properly documenting the variations...

Answer (score 1):

The icon with the wrench signifies that it's a **property**.

The icon that shows a blue brick signifies the variable or whatever that is, is **protected**.

The pink cube icon shows it is some sort of **subroutine or function or a method**.

And the icon with that yellow thing shows that it is some sort of **class**!

Comment: I actually do not know what that yellow thing is called...